# Handling multiple dates on fact table with performance concerns

Tags: sql-server, database-design, datetime, dimensional-modeling, facttable

I am working on a simple data marts and has once again stumbled with the handling date and time.

[image]

This is a design on a vehicle maintenance form records to collect the status record/remarks for analytics/visualisation. There are several date and time columns in this fact table.

My questions are

1. Fact table should be narrow and long, and not wide. With this many date and time columns, it makes the table wide. If I query a `LEFT JOIN` with `Vehicle.dim` and `VehMaintenance.fact` to consolidate all details and output in the frontend, wouldn't the performance be horrible? Now imagine I have even more dimensions to join, then doing a `LEFT JOIN` onto the `fact table` will make it even more wider. I think my design is horribly wrong.
2. `Vehicle.dim` is linked back to `Date.dim`. I read somewhere that `dimension table` should not link back to another unless it is a `snowflake schema` and if it is a `parent / child`. Is it still fine to link both `dimension table` like this?

Take note that my `fact table` will be batch updated on a 15 minutes basis from a data warehouse. It will always be an `INSERT` query to insert records (there will be multiple same records, except the date will be different on these same records). There will be `NULL` in some of the `date columns`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fact table should be narrow and long, and not wide. With this many date and time columns, it makes the table wide.

No your fact table isn't wide, it only has 11 columns. Once you have over 100 columns or so you can start calling it wide.

> If I query a `LEFT JOIN` with `Vehicle.dim` and `VehMaintenance.fact` to consolidate all details and output in the frontend, wouldn't the performance be horrible?

Not if your tables are indexed properly, not at all. Doesn't matter how many rows you have in each of them then. You'd be joining two narrow tables, which also doesn't really matter how wide they are either. Performance is based on your use cases and how you architect (e.g. index) to those use cases.

Without seeing actual queries, no one can advise you conclusively, but if you're just doing a simple `LEFT JOIN` between two tables, then there's no reason you should have any issues.

> `Vehicle.dim` is linked back to `Date.dim`. I read somewhere that `dimension table` should not link back to another unless it is a `snowflake schema` and if it is a `parent / child`.

This is happening because your table `Vehicle.dim` is not a true dimensions table. Rather it's a quasi-dimensions/facts table. This is because it contains a fact column called `manufactured_date`. In an ideal star schema design, you would have a `Vehicle.fact` table that stores the `manufactured_date` instead, and sits between your two dimensions tables, `Date.dim` and `Vehicle.dim`, that way you're not linking two dimension tables directly.

> Is it still fine to link both `dimension table` like this?

Again, it's not ideal because you're heading towards a snowflake design. This *can* lead to inefficiencies from a performance standpoint, and can lead to some logical data issues (e.g. redundant data showing in the wrong context) depending on your use cases. But it doesn't look like it would be the end of the world either in this specific design, if you kept it this way.

I'd still personally recommend creating a `Vehicle.fact` table so you can aim for a star schema, especially for future-proofing should you add more facts about a `Vehicle`, later on.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback again JD. I am curious, is it better to avoid snowflake design in general? If we talk about Kimball methodology, wouldn't a data warehouse of his design (consisting of many data marts) becomes a snowflake?

Comment: @user3118602 No prob! I'll preface by saying I'm not a data warehouse expert, so I only speak from the experience I do have. I've been told by other data warehouse experts that in general it is better to avoid the snowflake design for performance and logical inconsistencies that can arise when querying the data. I'm not familiar with the Kimball methodology, but having multiple data marts isn't an issue in of itself. Even in a perfect star schema, multiple fact tables can be the center of each of their own star, sharing dimension tables between each star.